# How to transpose panel data into correct form in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, transpose, panel-data

So I am struggling to transform my data into a panel data form so that I can start analysing it. So far I have imported and merged my excel files so my data looks something like this (bear in mind the real data has far more rows and far more variables)

```
   Company Name   Date                Market Share  ...5.x  ...6.x  ...7.x  ...8.x
   <chr>          <dttm>              <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
 1 NA             NA                  FY0           FY-1    FY-2    FY-3    FY-4  
 2 Kimball Elect  2020-06-29 23:00:00 4020          4422    4232    4111    4003
 3 Mercadolibre   2019-12-31 00:00:00 8357          2843    2653    2222    2134
 4 Lazard Ltd     2019-12-31 00:00:00 47700         45061   45050   43280   42281
```

As you can see, row 1 exists to specify the lags in time for the market share variable, where FY0 is equal to the date in the date column and then FY-1 is the year before that, FY-2 is two years before etc.  In the original excel files, the market share column was multi-index so all the lags were associated with the market share column, however when importing to R only FY0 remained associated with the market share column and all the other columns were auto-filled with '...5.x  ...6.x  ...7.x  ...8.x'.

I essentially want to transform my data to look like this:

```
    Company Name   Date    Market Share 
 1  Kimball Elect  2020    4020          
 2  Kimball Elect  2019    4422
 3  Kimball Elect  2018    4232
 4  Kimball Elect  2017    4111 
 5  Kimball Elect  2016    4003
 6  Mercadolibre   2019    8357    
 7  Mercadolibre   2018    2843
 8  Mercadolibre   2017    2653
 9  Mercadolibre   2016    2222
 10 Mercadolibre   2015    2134
 11 Lazard Ltd     2019    47700
 12 Lazard Ltd     2018    45061
 13 Lazard Ltd     2017    45050
 14 Lazard Ltd     2016    43280
 15 Lazard Ltd     2015    42281
```

So basically I want to transpose the data in a way that makes the time lags into rows and then associate each lag (FY0, FY-1, FY-2...' with a date/year determined by the date column minus the lag ie. FY0 = 2020-06-29 so FY-1 = 2019-06-29.

Thanks in advance for anyone who is able to help as I feel this is quite tricky to do in R!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the following

**Data**

```
> example <- data.frame(Company = "Kimball", date = "2020", FY0 = 4200, FY1 = 4210)
> example
  Company date  FY0  FY1
1 Kimball 2020 4200 4210
```

**Code**

```
example %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_longer(., c("FY0", "FY1")) %>% 
               dplyr::group_by(Company) %>% 
                      dplyr::mutate(Years = as.numeric(date) - (row_number() - 1)) %>%    
                                   dplyr::select(-date, -name)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Company [1]
  Company value Years
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Kimball  4200  2020
2 Kimball  4210  2019
```

---

**EDIT**

To address your concerns:

(1) The first row contains the variables `FY0`, ... . Hence you just need to replace the columns of the third, fourth, ..., last column with the values of the first row minus the first two columns, i.e. `colnames(df) <- df[1, 3:(ncols(df))]`.

(2) The `row_number()` pertains to the *grouping*! Hence, for each group, i.e. firm, the numbering will start again at 1! No worries there.

Comment: Hi Taufi, thanks for this. I get the intuition behind it and the pivot_longer function definitely seems useful however I have 2 concerns:

1. How do I deal with the fact that FY0, FY-1, FY-2 etc arent actually columns but are actually subsets of the wider market share column?

2. I see in your mutate function you make the year = date - row number which although I can see will work for the 1 firm example, how would I do this for the 100th firm where the row number is not at all related to the year?

Comment: I edited my solution. Does that answer your questions?